# Anonymous Pipes c# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pipe, ipc

I am trying to achieve IPC with two WPF Application running on the same machine.I need to achieve something similar to [Example using Winform](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087779/Anonymous-Pipes-Made-Easy). Can some one convert the below code to WPF/C# as you can see the delegate invoke is directly dependent on Winform Control,

```
if (theArgs.Length == 0)
        {
            this.Text = "Pipe Server";
            pipe = new AnonymousPipes("Server end of the pipe.", Application.ExecutablePath, "additionalArgs=your_own_command_line_args_here", delegate(String msg)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    this.lbTextIn.Items.Add(msg);
                });
            }, delegate()
            {
                // We're disconnected!
                try
                {
                    if (!this.IsDisposed)
                    {
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            this.lbTextIn.Items.Add("Client disconnected!");
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Pipe Client";
            pipe = new AnonymousPipes("Client end of the pipe.");
            pipe.ConnectToPipe(theArgs[0], delegate(String msg)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    lbTextIn.Items.Add(msg);
                });
            }, delegate()
            {
                // We're disconnected!
                this.Close();
            });
        }
```

The implementation of Wrapper class is below,

```
public class AnonymousPipes
{
    private String clientPath;
    private AnonymousPipeServerStream outGoingServerPipe;
    private AnonymousPipeServerStream inComingServerPipe;
    private PipeStream clientIn;
    private PipeStream clientOut;
    private Process pipeClient;
    private String incomingHandle;
    private String outgoingHandle;
    private StreamWriter ssw;
    private StreamWriter csw;
    private bool serverMode;
    private bool running;
    private CallBack callback;
    private DisconnectEvent disconnectEvent;
    private String msgError;
    private String name;

    public delegate void CallBack(String msg);
    public delegate void DisconnectEvent();
    public String ermsg;

    public bool isConnected()
    {
        return running;
    }

    public String GetPipeName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public AnonymousPipes(String pipeName)
    {
        this.name = pipeName;
    }

    private String StartPipeServer()
    {
        serverMode = true;
        outGoingServerPipe = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
        inComingServerPipe = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

        return outGoingServerPipe.GetClientHandleAsString() + ":::" + inComingServerPipe.GetClientHandleAsString();
    }

    public AnonymousPipes(String pipeName, String clientPath, String cmdLineArgs, CallBack callback,
        DisconnectEvent disconnectEvent)
    {
        String args;
        this.clientPath = clientPath;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.disconnectEvent = disconnectEvent;
        this.name = pipeName;
        this.running = true;

        serverMode = true;

        args = StartPipeServer() + " " + cmdLineArgs;

        try
        {
            pipeClient = new Process();
            pipeClient.StartInfo.FileName = clientPath;
            pipeClient.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            pipeClient.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pipeClient.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ermsg = ex.Message;
            running = false;
            return;
        }

        outGoingServerPipe.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
        inComingServerPipe.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

        ssw = new StreamWriter(outGoingServerPipe);
        ssw.AutoFlush = true;
        ssw.WriteLine("SYNC");

        outGoingServerPipe.WaitForPipeDrain();

        new Thread(delegate ()
        {

            using (StreamReader isr = new StreamReader(inComingServerPipe))
            {
                String tmp;
                while (running && inComingServerPipe.IsConnected)
                {
                    tmp = isr.ReadLine();
                    if (tmp != null)
                    {
                        callback(tmp);
                    }
                }
            }

            running = false;
            disconnectEvent();

        }).Start();
    }

    public bool SendText(String msg)
    {
        return SendText(msg, ref msgError);
    }

    public bool SendText(String msg, ref String errMsg)
    {
        if (serverMode)
        {
            try
            {
                ssw.WriteLine(msg);
                outGoingServerPipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errMsg = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                csw.WriteLine(msg);
                clientOut.WaitForPipeDrain();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToPipe(String clientHandles, CallBack callback, DisconnectEvent disconnectEvent)
    {
        String[] handles = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(clientHandles, ":::");
        this.incomingHandle = handles[0];
        this.outgoingHandle = handles[1];
        this.callback = callback;
        this.disconnectEvent = disconnectEvent;
        running = true;
        serverMode = false;

        new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            clientIn = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, this.incomingHandle);
            clientOut = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, this.outgoingHandle);

            csw = new StreamWriter(clientOut);
            csw.AutoFlush = true;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientIn))
            {
                string temp;

                do
                {
                    temp = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                while (!temp.StartsWith("SYNC") && running);

                while (running && clientIn.IsConnected)
                {
                    temp = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (temp != null) { callback(temp); }
                }

                running = false;
                disconnectEvent();
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        running = false;

        try
        {
            pipeClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            outGoingServerPipe.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            inComingServerPipe.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            clientOut.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            clientIn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            ssw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        try
        {
            csw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF doesn't affect how IPC works. What you really ask is how to modify the UI from another thread, and the answer is - not like that at all. Not since 2010 when Tasks were introduced and not earlier either. The article you followed is bad

Comment: I suggest you check the docs instead, especially [How to: Use Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication). A PipeStream is still a stream, which means you can use `async/await` to read data from it and update the UI, without starting raw threads, using a wrapper or having to use `Invoke`.

Comment: [Progress reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?redirectedfrom=MSDN#progress-reporting-optional) is available through the `Process<T>`, [cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?redirectedfrom=MSDN#cancellation-optional) through `CancellationToken`

Comment: Thanks  for suggestion, I am trying to find a good example on IPC using anynomous pipes between wpf to wpf communication.

Comment: Again, WPF has *nothing* to do with IPC. You could just use the doc example to set up client and server streams. Your *actual* question is how to modify the UI from another thread. Both for Winforms and WPF the answer since 2012 is `async/await`, not `Invoke`. If you check the documentation example for pipes you'll notice it's a *lot* simpler than your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i need to understand the basic of IPC here

Comment: can i ask if IPC using Anyonomous pipes is the way to go for my requirement? I need to send events from two process (wpf) to each other within windows system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219273/discussion-between-vinay-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Invoke` with `Dispatcher.Invoke`, e.g.:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate ()
{
    this.lbTextIn.Items.Add(msg);
});
```